# Area of a right triangle with its angle bisector and hypotenuse

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> A right triangle $ABC$ is given with right angle at $C$. If $AB=a$ and the angle bisector of $A$ is $AL=l$, find the area of the triangle $ABC$.

The angles of the triangle $ABL$ are $\dfrac{\alpha}{2}, 90-\alpha$ and $90+\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$, where $\alpha$ is the angle $BAC$.

The law of sines gives $$\dfrac{\sin\left(90+\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{\sin(90-\alpha)}=\dfrac{a}{l}$$ which is equivalent to $$\dfrac{\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}{\cos\alpha}=\dfrac{a}{l}$$ If we use that $\cos\alpha=2\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}-1$, the last equality becomes an equation for $\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}=x>0$. We would have $$\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}=\dfrac{a}{l}\left(2\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha}{2}-1\right) \\ \dfrac{2a}{l} x^2-x-\dfrac{a}{l}=0 \\ 2ax^2-lx-a=0$$ The positive solution is $x=\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}=\dfrac{l+\sqrt{l^2+8a^2}}{4a}$.

By definition $\cos\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$ is $\dfrac{AC}{AL}$, so for $AC=b$ I got $$b=\dfrac{l^2+l\sqrt{l^2+8a^2}}{4a}$$ From here I don't see anything else except the Pythagorean theorem for $BC$ but it's pretty messy. I wish I could see something better. I tried letting Wolfram Alpha do the simplification, which probably avoids errors, but it's still ugly:

(l (√(8 a^2 + l^2) + l) √(a^2 - (l^2 (√(8 a^2 + l^2) + l)^2)/(16 a^2)))/(8 a)

I have tried to find a better way, but I keep coming back to expressions involving $b$ and the Pythagorean Theorem. For instance, the area of $\triangle ABC$ can be expressed as $\dfrac{c(a+b)}{2}$ where $c = |CL|$; but this doesn't simplify any more neatly.

Comment: Request diagram, because I am confused.  If the right angle is at $C$ then $\overline{AB}$ is the hypotenuse.  This means that $a > l.$  However, the official solution makes no sense unless $l > a.$  Please explain.

Comment: @user2661923, yep, I agree with you that the official answer makes no sense when I think about it. How do you conclude that $a>l$, though?

Comment: I suggest that you re-examine the exact wording of the problem, try to reverse engineer the problem composer's intent, and then overhaul your posting.   Your other alternative is to delete the posting, have a teacher resolve the confusion, and then re-post the problem.

Comment: @user2661923, there isn't a confusion. The problem still holds?! Just the authors' answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: As you indicated, under the assumption that the official answer is wrong, the Math seems messy.  How do you exclude the possibility that the official answer is correct and that either you have mis-worded the original problem, or the original problem was erroneously worded?

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-Be the right triangle $\triangle {ABC}$ as in the problem and let $a,b$ the sides forming the vertex $A$ where is the angle$2\alpha$. We have
$$b=l\cos(\alpha)=a\cos(2\alpha)\iff a(2\cos^2(\alpha)-1)=l\cos(\alpha)$$
$$2a\cos^2(\alpha)-l\cos(\alpha)-a=0$$ and
$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{l\pm\sqrt{l^2+8a^2}}{4a}$$
Finally the area $S$ is equal to $$\dfrac12ab\sin(2\alpha)=ab\cos(\alpha)\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

Comment: How is that a "neat simplification" in terms af $a$ and $l$?

Comment: Because  you have got $A$ in function of $a$ and $l$, data of the problem.